# jQuery: обработчик on не работает на созданный Javascript элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему обработчик `.on` не работает на вновь созданный  элемент стандартными методами JavaScript?

Но если элемент добавить с помощью `$("#main").append("<div id='test2'>test2</div>");`, то работает.

Получается, что нельзя совмещать: либо писать на jQuery, либо на JavaScript?

```js
$('#main').on('click', '#test1', function(e) {

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = name;
  div.innerHTML = 'test2';
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
  //$("#main").append("<div id='test2'>test2</div>"); - работает
});

$('#main').on('click', '#test2', function(e) {
  console.log('test2'); //не работает
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div id="test1">test1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте ему `div.id = 'test2'` для того, чтобы он работал.

```js
$('#main').on('click', '#test1', function(e) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = 'test2';
  div.innerHTML = 'test2';
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
  //$("#main").append("<div id='test2'>test2</div>"); - работает
});

$('#main').on('click', '#test2', function(e) {
  console.log('test2'); //работает
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div id="test1">test1</div>
</div>
```